# Bootstrap - Multi-column layout inside button dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple button dropdown. I need each row in the dropdown to be separated into 3 columns in order to place an edit and delete icon on each row (Snippet shows this better than I can explain)

I am having a really difficult time figuring out the best way to do this. The only way I came up with to halfway achieve this was to use col-* classes on the li elements, but since this list of items is dynamically generated, that was not a great solution since it would have required multiple loops to generate.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" style="display:block">Sales Tax</label>
      <div class="btn-group btn-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                5.795% <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="tax_rate_dropdown">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">7.5%</a>
                    <button style="background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button style="background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">8.5%</a>
                    <button style="background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button style="background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">9.5%</a>
                    <button style="background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button style="background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">10.5%</a>
                    <button style="background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button style="background-color: transparent;" type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create New Sales Tax</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: so a row consist of `7.5 %` value, edit icon, delete icon so three item in row. Am i right

Comment: Yep, exactly. But sometimes the percent might be something like 22.9739%, so I need to make sure that the edit and delete icons stay in line, even if the percentage string is longer or shorter. Essentially functioning like a table. I also need to be able to define the %, Edit, and Delete button all at once on a row by row level.

Comment: if you want  functioning like a table, why don't you try table.?

Comment: I definitely can do that, but I felt like there was probably a much better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to insert the following CSS (onto a new or existing `style.css` file) you could do something like this:

```
ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu>li {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; /* width of dropdown, adjust to suit your needs */
}

ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu>li>a,
ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu>li>button {
  display: table-cell;
}
ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu>li>button{
  float: right;
}

ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  width: 50%; /* this is only to align the numbers, adjust to suit your needs */
}
```

**See demo below:**

```css
ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu > li {
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /* width of dropdown, adjust to suit your needs */
}

ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu > li > a,
ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu > li > button {
    display: table-cell;
}

ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu > li > button {
    float: right;
}

ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%; /* this is only to align the numbers, adjust to suit your needs */
}

/* reducing HTML ;) */
ul#tax_rate_dropdown.dropdown-menu > li .btn-clear {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" style="display:block">Sales Tax</label>
        <div class="btn-group btn-block">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                5.795% <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="tax_rate_dropdown">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">1%</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">8.5%</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">9.55%</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">10.5555555555555%</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clear">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create New Sales Tax</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

adjusted dropdown width in demo

Comment: This is pretty close to working, but it doesn't keep the icons in line (See how the edit icon has shifted right on the 10.5% row) Additionally, if I don't make the ul wide enough with style:min-width, then the content sometimes wraps to a second line if the percentage is long. Is there a way to make the div stretch to fit the contents?

Comment: @Kevin I updated my answer - do you foresee the percentage to have a variable (or unlimited) number of decimal digits?

Comment: Yes. In all actuality, the percentages will have labels as well, so it might be: CA State Sales Tax - 5.5%, National Sales Tax: 10.9%, etc...

Comment: @Kevin check the latest update, let me know if you notice something else

Comment: Man that is a thing of beauty. Thank you so much for your help! This seems to work very well on all size parent containers and screen resolutions so I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of `css` can do, your need.

add below css to your file

```
ul a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Don't use `in-line` to style instead use external css.

reduced 253 characters by removing `style="background-color: transparent;"`
and simple adding

```
.btn{
background-color: transparent;
}
```

```css
ul a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btn {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" style="display:block">Sales Tax</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                5.795% <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="tax_rate_dropdown">
        <li>
          <a href="#">22.97395566665565%</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">9.99%</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">1%</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-edit text-primary"></i>
                    </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"></i>
                    </button>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create New Sales Tax</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: by overriding `.btn` you are affecting the entire bootstrap library since it is who defines it (this may not always be desirable) - instead, create your own class and apply that one to the `buttons` to narrow the scope of the elements affected by the added `CSS` code

Comment: The inline styles are just temporary while it's being developed. They'll be moved out to classes. I like your snippet because I WANT to understand flexbox, but unfortunately, your icons aren't staying in line either. They are moving left and right, depending on the length of the percentage string. Thank you for your help!